# Get ComboBox ValueMember from DataGridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to get the ValueMember of a ComboBox that is in a Datagridview cell from a button click event:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter t3DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Adok;", conn));
            OleDbCommandBuilder t3Command = new OleDbCommandBuilder(t3DataAdapter);
            t3DataAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Adok");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row4 = ds.Tables["Adok"].NewRow();
                row4["HoltID"] = ((ComboBox)dataGridView3["HoltID", i]).ValueMember ;// I would like to get something like this

                ds.Tables["Adok"].Rows.Add(row4);
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: `row4["HoltID"] = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView3["HoltID", i]).ValueMember;` -- Isn't the `ValueMember`'s value always the same string?

Comment: no, the ValueMember is changing when user selects a value from Combobox from another row

Comment: No, it doesn't. `ValueMember`  represents the name of the Member that provides the `Value`. The counterpart is `DisplayMember`, which represents the name of the Member that provides the presentation / description etc. -- You probably want the Cell's `Value` (represented by the underlying ComboBox's `SelectedValue`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created a ComboBox in CellBeginEdit event, but in the CellEndEdit event I hid it and the value was added to the cell value.
(So the cell type was a DataGridViewTextBoxCell at the end, not a DataGridViewComboBoxCell)

So I used the the Tag property of the cell in CellEndEdit to save also the ID.

Now, everything works.